# Assign a type of deep key to its ancestor to create a new type in Typescipt

Tags: typescript

**Use Case**

Consider a query for a database access (all fictional). Lets say an object like

```
const query = {
    students: { projection: { name: "" } },
    courses: { projection: { title: "" } },
}
```

specifies the query. Each key is a different db table and projection tells what fields to retrieve. It also tells the type of each field by having a value of that type.

**Goal**

I want to make a type that can take this query object as a parameter (generic) and produce the result type that will be the response type of db. The above query will have a result of

```
result = {
    students: { name: "Lorem Ipsum" },
    courses: { title: "Hello World" }
}
```

and result type will be

```
{
    students: { name: string },
    courses: { title: string }
}
```

**What Have I tried**

I have tried something similar to

```
type Projection<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T
type Result<P extends Projection, T extends Record<string, {projection: P}>> = Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]['projection']>
```

but the resulting type is

```
{
    students: { name: string } | { title: string },
    ...same for rest of the fields
}
```

**Whats missing**

My solution cannot associate each key with its own type. The `Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]>` takes union of all the keys which is correct behavior but not the desired one.

**Any Help will be Appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
const query = {
    students: { projection: { name: "" } },
    courses: { projection: { title: "" } },
}

type Projection = Record<string, unknown>;
type Result<T extends Record<string, { projection: Projection }>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [F in keyof T[K]['projection']]: T[K]['projection'][F]
  }
}

type X = Result<typeof query>;
```

This resolves `X` as:

```
type X = {
  students: {
    name: string;
  };
  courses: {
    title: string;
  };
}
```